How can I properly daemonize Celery to ensure it runs continuously without any issues?
My celery works locally but when I try celery daemonization at server side, it does not work. When I run this code I can see there is a successful connection with redis. code
enter image description here
But I am getting error, failed to start celery service..enter image description here
Can someone please help me? I run of ideas how can I solve this issue?
My recouces at my instance. 4 GB RAM, 2 vCPUs, 80 GB SSD.

provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example including journal details
